# DotNet Core: 'dotnet test' command starts 4 '.Net Core Host' processes when only two of them are needed for test execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nunit

I made a NUnit test project on .NetCore 2.2.

The project has only one test(three lines of code, nothing serious) and when I start it with 'dotnet test' command, four '.Net Core Host' processes are created which takes up to 100-120 MB for a single test:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoxtW.png

If I kill the process with PID 22100, the next one with PID 27008 is gone as well, but the test is still executing, result is returned(everything as expected).

By executing the same test with this command 'dotnet test --no-build', the usage of the memory is reduced, but not so much:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL9Wo.png

**And my questions are:**

1. Do you know why we have 4 processes when only two are needed from my point view while testing this?
2. Is there a way to reduce the processes, so only the needed ones to be started or to reduce the memory usage? If you start some project with more tests in parallel(20-30 in parallel), the memory usage is up to 3-4 GB of RAM.

**I'm using:**

- .NetCore 2.2(I tried also with .NetCore 3 and the results are the
  same)
- NUnit 3.12
- Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK 15.9.0

Thanks in advance.